# mvc 2 - 404 error page not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, http-status-code-404

I am getting a 404 error when I start up my mvc 2 project. I followed the guide here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/asp-net/asp-net-from-scratch-mvc/

I haven't set up a start page (Which I figured out to be a normal newbie mistake) and I've edited my global.asax class to look like below so it contains the right route. I just can't figure out why it gives me a 404.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "CreateUserController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
```

Here's my CreateUserController:

```
public class CreateUserController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /CreateUser/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult AddLinks()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

My Project looks like this:

- Controllers

  - CreateUserController.cs
- Models ((This is empty for now))
- Views

  - CreateUser

    - Index.aspx
  - Shared

    - Site.Master
- global.asax
- Web.Config

I am totally new at mvc 2, I've worked with normal web forms for about 2 months now. Let me know if you need the aspx files, but I just need it to find my controller, at this point I just want another error.

Comment: Put some breakpoints in your code and let us know where it's failing.

Comment: Well it doesn't find any of the pages, So which code would be run that I can set up break points in?

Comment: I assume your current Project tree actually has the CreateUser folder nested beneath the Views folder, and the Views folder at the root of your project -- correct? Are you getting the 404 error through Cassini, IIS Express, or IIS? If IIS, what version of IIS?

Comment: Sorry I messed up the project tree :) I just corrected it thank you. My Project has not been deployed I just run it on it on the development server. So the IIS shouldn't be a problem right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "CreateUser", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

controller should be "CreateUser" not "CreateUserController"

you can see this hint in your file

```
        // GET: /CreateUser/
```

Comment: Now I feel stupid, Thanks a lot though, I feel like I've been trying everything. After 2 hours I can finally get started on mvc :)

Comment: Remember convention over configuration :)

Comment: hehe.. I guess there's some things I have to get used to. In my world writing the full name would be more precise, But I guess it's read as "CreateUserControllerController". I'm sure I'll remember this from now on.